# receiving and sending sms through gsm modem

Tags: java, sms

How can I receive SMS through a GSM modem so that I can use this SMS for further processing and send back a reply SMS.
I do not have particular idea on how to achieve this.......
I prefer using java language for this project and I am using Linux OS.

Answer (score 5):

You might want to give a look at [SMSLib](https://github.com/tdelenikas/smslib):

> SMSLib is a programmer's library for sending and receiving SMS
>   messages via a GSM modem or mobile phone. SMSLib also supports a few
>   bulk SMS operators.

Comment: SMSLib is no longer maintained.

Answer (score 3):

To send an SMS using a 3G modem, you need to use the appropriate `AT` commands. First you need to set the modem to text mode:

```
AT+CMGF=1
```

Then you send your message:

```
AT+CMGS=<number><CR>
<message><CTRL-Z>
```

Where `<CR>` is a carriage return (ASCII 13), and `<message>` is the message you want to send, `<CTRL-Z>` is ASCII 26, and `<number>` is the number you want to send your message to.

To read received messages, you do this:

```
AT+CMGL=<stat><CR>
```

Where `<stat>` is one of: `"ALL"`, `"REC UNREAD"`, `"REC READ"` (with the quotes), meaning all messages, unread messages, and read messages respectively.

To do this in Java you'll need to use the Java communications API. Here's a short example:
http://java.sun.com/products/javacomm/reference/docs/API_users_guide_3.html

Comment: that's exactly what I mean :) +1

Comment: Hey... The links is for API is dead... Please could you update (since it was pointing to a specific example illustrating AT use...)...

Answer (score 3):

hi i'm using RXTX library the code goes here!.. and its works fine for me , i searched a lot of things to get correct method finaly got the key to sms!.. :D

```
                String mValue = "AT\r";// strating to communicate with port starts here!
    mOutputToPort.write(mValue.getBytes());
    mOutputToPort.flush();
    Thread.sleep(500);
    mInputFromPort.read(mBytesIn);
    value = new String(mBytesIn);
    System.out.println("Response from Serial Device: "+value);
                mValue = "AT+cmgf=1\r";
    mOutputToPort.write(mValue.getBytes());
                mOutputToPort.flush();
                mValue="at+cmgs=\" Mobile number\"\r";
                System.out.print(mValue);
                mOutputToPort.write(mValue.getBytes());
            mOutputToPort.flush();
            mValue="at+cmgs="\032";//calling ctrl+z
                System.out.print(mValue);
                mOutputToPort.write(mValue.getBytes());
            mOutputToPort.flush();
          mOutputToPort.close(); 
    mInputFromPort.close();
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look on [SMSJ](http://smsj.sourceforge.net/): a fully functional library that allows sending and receiving SMS using either GSM modem or several popular web services.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [Java SMSLib API](http://smslib.org/).

From the web site : "SMSLib is a programmer's library for sending and receiving SMS messages via a GSM modem or mobile phone. SMSLib also supports a few bulk SMS operators."

Answer (score 0):

You shoud take a look at your modem manual. Some devices support telnet connection and you can sent **AT commands** via command line.

If this is your case you have to learn about (sometimes specific for each device), and code an application that uses telnet to communicate with your modem.
[Apache Commons Net project](http://commons.apache.org/net/) can be useful.

Some AT commands guides:

- http://www.portech.com.tw/data/Siemens%20TC35I_AT.pdf
- http://www.sierrawireless.com/resources/faq/AirLink/Redwing/Redwing_GPRS_UsersGuide.pdf

Alternatively you can try to use one of the libraries suggested by others.

Comment: "application that uses telnet" - this is a common misconception. Telnet is a _network_ _protocol_. It's a rather simple network protocol, and telnet clients usually implement a terminal emulator of some sort, and so clients are often abused to do other tasks.

Comment: @cha0site probably my explaination is not "tecnically exact", sorry for my bad english! what I wanted to say is that you can write an application that communicate with the modem via telnet...

Comment: You're correct, up until the "via telnet" part. Telnet has nothing to do with communicating with modems. You need to use some sort of serial port interface (even if the modem is connected with USB - those often emulate serial ports).

Answer (score 0):

U can use many methods ...

- SMS Enabler
- SMS Lib for java
- Ozeki sms gateway

For recieving SMS best and simple solution will be
SMSenabler it will save your SMS instantly to file or database and u can retrieve it
Free version supports upto 12 characters 
and if you want to send sms then you can use [enter link description here][Ozeki] Ozeki sms server gateway